# NSDateFormatter returns nil in swift and iOS SDK 8.0

Tags: ios

I am reading the tutorial provided by Raywenderlich, [Chapter 29 What’s New with Testing](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83963/ios-8-tutorials-now-available), and run into a strange problem.

Following is the code in the tutorial converting a string into date:

```
// Convert date string to date.
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"
var date: NSDate? = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
```

The dateString is of the form

```
2014-06-21 14:56:00 EST
```

However, the date variable is always nil.

NOTE: when playing this code in the playground, it works properly, as the image shows:

[image]

I am working in iOS SDK 8.0. Is it a bug of the SDK?

---

Updated

I am testing using a latest iPod Touch with iOS 8.

Comment: Is this on a device or on the simulator?  You may be bit by the "locale feature".

Comment: @HotLicks, running on a device installed iOS 8

Comment: Bummer.  Works for me in a playground, simulator and iPhone 5s running iOS 7.1

Comment: Confirming that this perfectly works for me in the playground (Xcode 6.0.1), iPhone 6, and simulator (iOS 8)

Comment: @MinnesotaSteve,I am testing using a latest iPod Touch with iOS 8.

Comment: @ev0lution,I am testing using a latest iPod Touch with iOS 8.

Comment: And have you set the 12/24 switch contrary to your locale?

Answer (score 13):

When you set a `dateFormat` string you must also set the `locale` property to something that is compatible with the format provided. Otherwise the locale will be based on the device settings which may not be compatible.

The date format you provided here will work with the "en" locale but it will not work with many others, such as "eu". Here's an example:

```
let dateString = "2014-06-21 14:56:00 EST"

let localeStr = "eu" // this will give nil
let localeStr = "us" // this will succeed

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: localeStr)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"
var date: NSDate? = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
```

The problem here is "EST" which only exists in the north america. In all other locales it is an invalid timezone. If you change your date string to this:

```
"2014-06-21 14:56:00 UTC-5"
```

Then it the date will correctly format no matter what value `locale` is set to.

Comment: I have watched your edits over the past couple of minutes and you are mostly correct about "EST". Timezones aren't standardised at all, which makes them very annoying to work with. Here in Australia I actually do see AEST rather than EST most of the time, but Apple docs disagree. According to them, "EST" is a valid timezone in Australia and the US: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: @ev0lution yes but by my testing "EST" gives nil if the locale is `en_AU` while "AEST" works with the Australian locale. I figured this out after posting so amended my edits a few times then eventually just removed it.

Comment: Interestingly... if the locale is "au" then "EST" works. I suppose there is probably a reason for that. For same reason though EST under "au" identifier gives the same time (5:56am) as EST under "us", so I think there's a bug somewhere. Best to stick to proper timezone offsets (UTC-5) if possible.

Comment: That's very strange, I don't know why they would allow AEST in `en_AU` but not `au`. I agree that there must be a bug - at the very least the fact their docs say that EST is valid for Australia, despite it actually returning the US EST timezone.

Comment: Locale identifier is basically formatted with '{language}[_{territory}]'. There is no "territory" only locales. For example, `eu` is the locale for 'Basque' language, `us` is invalid because there is no language named "us"

Comment: @ev0lution Where did you find in docs that `EST` timezone is valid for `en_AU` locale?

Comment: @rintaro They don't specify `en_AU`, they say '“EST” refers to Eastern Time in both the United States and Australia'. I'm 99.9% sure it was in the page I linked to in my first comment, but it seems to be gone now. The same warning can be found on this page under `timeZoneWithAbbreviation:`: https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: That page also says it's unsafe to use terms like EST except for special cases like "UTC" or "GMT".

Comment: This is also happening on my App that has been updated to Swift 3.0. Everything works fine for iPhone 5 upwards, but when I tested my App on an iPhone 4s I needed to add formatter.locale to make it work.

Answer (score 5):

`NSDateFormatter`'s behaviors are heavily depends on it's `locale`.
By default, it uses device locale.
If you want consistent result from it, You should manually specify the `locale`. In most cases, `en_US_POSIX` is the best.

[The document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/dataformatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW7) says:

> If you're working with fixed-format dates, you should first set the locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed format. In most cases the best locale to choose is en_US_POSIX, a locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results regardless of both user and system preferences. en_US_POSIX is also invariant in time (if the US, at some point in the future, changes the way it formats dates, en_US will change to reflect the new behavior, but en_US_POSIX will not), and between platforms (en_US_POSIX works the same on iPhone OS as it does on OS X, and as it does on other platforms).

Like this:

```
let dateString = "2014-06-21 14:56:00 EST"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"
var date: NSDate? = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
```