# How to get time difference in minutes in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, closures

Though the question is related to time difference, I think i may have an async / closure related problem.

So I have a dateTime coming from a webserver on my iOS app via Alamofire. I do a comparison as the following:

```
 let recordedDate = obj[0]["time"].stringValue //TIME FROM SERVER

 let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
 let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(recordedDate)
 let elapsedTime = (Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(date!)) / 60 / 60) 
 //THE PROBLEM IS THAT date IS NIL. 

 if elapsedTime > 1{
    self.isActiveLabel.text = "Offline"
 }else{
   self.isActiveLabel.text = "Active"
 }
```

So from my troubleshooting, it looks like date didnt finish processing by the time elapsedTime is calculated therefore returning a "Found Nil" problem.

This problem doesn't happen on the simulator so that rules out the posibility that date is really empty. Problem happens only once deployed on device. How do I run epalsedTime after date is ready? Or is there a better practice to achieve this.

Any wisdom or guidance is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: There are no asynchronous calls in your code, so control will flow from top to bottom.

Comment: If `recordedDate` is not `nil` but `date` is, then the problem is that the date string doesn't match the format you handed to the date formatter.

Comment: You have a possibly erroneous space after `ss` in the formatter. Also, you don't appear to be unwrapping your optionals.

Comment: Ok the unwrapped was a copy paste mistake. recordedDate on the DB is "2016-06-22 09:03:06" and date is "2016-06-22 01:03:06 +0000" . Do you know why the time changed after formatting?

Comment: One problem might be that you're ignoring time zones

Comment: The time didn't change after parsing or formatting. Your device's (or simulator's) time zone is +0800 (eight hours ahead of) UTC, and `NSDateFormatter` uses your device's time zone by default. `2016-06-22 09:03:06 +0800` and `2016-06-22 01:03:06 +0000` are the same number of seconds since the reference date.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, it's basically:

`dateFormatter.dateFromString("2016-06-22 01:03:06 +0000")`

returns `nil`.

If this is the case, it's because the date format is mismatched:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z  => 2016-06-22 01:03:06 +0000
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss    => 2016-06-22 01:03:06
```

Try the code below to deal with two possible formats:

```
+ (NSDate *)dateFromDateString:(NSString *)dateString {

    NSDate *date = nil;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]; // or something else
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:timeZone];

    // Try two ways to cover the web server return
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
    date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];

    if (date == nil) {
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
        date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
    }

    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so for my issue all I had to do was add the following:

```
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "us")
```

It worked perfectly after that. It was try and error. If anyone can explain why? I will be happy to mark as accepted answer.

Thank you all for your guidance.

Ref: [NSDateFormatter returns nil in swift and iOS SDK 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26153381/nsdateformatter-returns-nil-in-swift-and-ios-sdk-8-0)