# SWIFT 3 unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (works perfect in simulator)

Tags: swift3

My code works perfectly in simulator, but it pops this "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" warning when I tried to run it on my iPhone and iPad.

Strange thing is, this error didn't occur when I tried to get the value of a variable, it happened when I tried to create an object with the values I got:

[image]

"pName" and "pQuestion" are the variables with values, but as you can see, once I tried to give these value to the attributes of my object, they just became nil.

This bit of the code really behaved in the simulator, somehow it just keeps acting out on a real device.

Comment: Did you add an exceptional breakpoint to see where your app crash?

Comment: It crashed when I tried to append the object into an array. And right above that "let question: Question? = nil" line, that commented line of code was what I started with, and back then the app crashed at that line with the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

What Swift is telling you is totally correct. Your `question` variable is nil when you are assigning values to it.
Don't you wanna initialise it before you start putting values into it?

I think what you are looking for is

`let question = Question(name: pName, question: pQuestion)`

Comment: That's exactly what I've started with, and the whole thing just crashed when it gets to that line, with the exact same error.

Comment: That is strange. could you show the entire function? Or better, class?

Comment: I know what's wrong, because I'm in Australia and I didn't set locale for the date variable, and it is one of the attributes of the object, so in the original code when I tried to create the question object I'm actually unwrapping the pDate which is nil. Anyway, thanks for helping out! Now I know I can't "let question: Question = nil" neither :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I know whats wrong with my code.

Like Hunaid Hassan said, my current code will just get nil out of the object.

The reason my original code didn't work is because, one of the attributes is a Date variable, and because I'm in Australia, when the app runs on a real device the Date I get will be nil because I didn't set the locale.

Here's my original code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUxR7.png)

And here's the fix I found to set the locale:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWD53.png)
ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26154583/7578872

Comment: Please include code in your questions/answers rather than links to screen shots.